# {flex:1} is not working properly in React Native

Tags: react-native

If I understand correctly -- making the outermost container as "flex: 1" should let the component span the whole screen.

However, the code I wrote is not working properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function test() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 5 }}>
            <Text>test</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

[The simulator screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56aLF.png)

Can anyone please point out where I did wrong?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Where are you calling this component? Yes, the flex will expand, but it is dependent on that parent component container. It looks like your parent is the one restricting this component.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I figured it out -- there was in fact an even outer <View></View> restraining it in App.js file.

Comment: Glad that helped. I added an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you calling this component? Yes, the flex will expand, but it is dependent on that parent component container. It looks like your parent is the one restricting this component.

Ensure the parent is also flexing and filling the content. Here is some more details around flex layout: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to import the Component as a class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default test extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 5 }}>
            <Text>test</Text>
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out -- there was in fact an even outer <View></View> restraining it in App.js file. Thanks though!